# Yii2 - createUrl() with array of params?

Tags: php, yii2

According to the [Yii2 documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-urlmanager.html#createUrl()-detail) , I am supposed to be building the URL like following:

```
$appUrl = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl([Yii::$app->controller->id . '/' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id,'p1' => 'v1','p2' => 'v2'] , null);
```

It outputs:

> /index.php?r=users%2Findex&p1=v1&p2=v2

Which is the correct output. Now, what if I have an array of params that I directly want to pass to the `createUrl()` method? The following code explains my problem:

```
$arrayParams = ['p1' => 'v1' , 'p2' => 'v2'];
$appUrl = Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl([Yii::$app->controller->id . '/' . Yii::$app->controller->action->id,$arrayParams] , null);
```

The output in this case is:

> /index.php?r=users/index&1[p1]=v1&1[p2]=v2

Whereas the output should have been:

> index.php?r=users/index&p1=v1&p2=v2

Please note that `$arrayParams` is generated by another method and I can't extract all the keys and values and pass them one by one in `createUrl()`. That would be very costly IMO. How do I achieve this using Yii's api?

Comment: For only one parameter: `<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(["post/view","id"=>$post->id]) ?>`

Comment: It's good to use ```Url::to()``` instead of ```Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl()```

Comment: @GermanKhokhlov I agree. I was relatively new to Yii 2 when I asked this. I had no idea that we have Url::to() method available back then. It's short and not linked to the $app, which I like.

Comment: @Gogol It's for other people who will find it. Cause I was looking for this shortcut when coming here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) to create required array structure.

```
$controller = Yii::$app->controller;
$arrayParams = ['p1' => 'v1' , 'p2' => 'v2'];

$params = array_merge(["{$controller->id}/{$controller->action->id}"], $arrayParams);

Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($params);
```

Comment: Sweet thank you. Exactly what I was looking for. Marking your answer as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

Same result you can achieve using `Yii::$app->controller->route`

```
$route = Yii::$app->controller->route;
$arrayParams = ['p1' => 'v1' , 'p2' => 'v2'];
$params = array_merge([$route], $arrayParams);
Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl($params);
```